# Is there any way to Browse webpage inside Perl Prima GUI?

Tags: perl, user-interface, perl-module

I have built a [`Prima`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Prima) GUI app for Windows.
My user will need to go to a webpage for a step that is processed by the server and return back to my app for further steps on the Web server output.
I want my user to be able to do it in the same window and need not go to the webpage via other web browesrs.
**Simply I want a browser functionality inside my Prima Window or Pod View.**
Is that possible.  Web search could not help me much.

Comment: If the webpage you need the user to interact with doesn't contain JavaScript, then perhaps you could use [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) to interact with the webpage on your user's behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Prima author here

I believe there are several ways to do this, but none of them is easy.

1) You can embed a native Windows browser control in the Prima window. Prima::Window->get_handle will get you the HWND id, which can be used as a parent handle where CLSID_WebBrowser OLE class can be stuffed into. You'll need XS/C hacking skills for this, see the embedding example f.ex. here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla

(upd: One could try the same OLE approach with Win32::OLE)

2) You can try to parse and visualize HTML yourself, limiting the parsing only to the elements the user needs to see. Unless there is only really basic HTML stuff, the task is rather big, even using Perl.

3) You can embed Webkit or Gecko control. I have no idea how hard that could be, but I believe not easy.

4) Not using Prima at all. Did you look at Gtk::HTML? However, *if* one can instantiate a Gtk widget and embed it into Prima window that possibly could work too.